# Javascript auto-clipboard doesn't copy data properly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having problems with my javascript/HTML autocopy function
When I click the button (`<i class="far fa-clipboard">`) it always copies the Donate BTC value instead of the ETH value or the LTC value.

This is my javascript code:

```
function autocopy() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

How I implemented it in html:

```
    <div class="donateto">           



        <p>                 
        <b>Donate BTC</b>
            <input type="text" value="3CMCRgEm8HVz3DrWaCCid3vAANE42jcEv9" id="myInput">
            <button onclick="autocopy()"><i class="far fa-clipboard"></i></button>


        <b> | Donate ETH</b>
            <input type="text" value="LTdsVS8VDw6syvfQADdhf2PHAm3rMGJvPX" id="myInput">
            <button onclick="autocopy()"><i class="far fa-clipboard"></i></button>   

        <b> | Donate LTC</b>
            <input type="text" value="30x0074709077B8AE5a245E4ED161C971Dc4c3C8E2B" id="myInput">
            <button onclick="autocopy()"><i class="far fa-clipboard"></i></button>             
        </p>

     </div>
```

Comment: Ids have to be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same ID for 3 elements, so 
var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
only copies the first element with the id.

```
 <div class="donateto">           



    <p>                 
    <b>Donate BTC</b>
        <input type="text" value="3CMCRgEm8HVz3DrWaCCid3vAANE42jcEv9" id="myInput">
        <button onclick="autocopy('myInput')">a<i class="far fa-clipboard"></i></button>


    <b> | Donate ETH</b>
        <input type="text" value="LTdsVS8VDw6syvfQADdhf2PHAm3rMGJvPX" id="myInput2">
        <button onclick="autocopy('myInput2')"><i class="far fa-clipboard"></i>a</button>   

    <b> | Donate LTC</b>
        <input type="text" value="30x0074709077B8AE5a245E4ED161C971Dc4c3C8E2B" id="myInput3">
        <button onclick="autocopy('myInput3')">a<i class="far fa-clipboard"></i></button>             
    </p>

 </div>
```

The js:

```
    function autocopy(id) {
      var copyText = document.getElementById(id);
     copyText.select();
     document.execCommand("Copy");
     alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
   }
```